# SQL Server 2008 R2 : can't connect SSMS. Self inflicted Injury

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I appear to have done myself a nasty.

While dinking around trying to get a CLR assy to run I deleted the user 'myserver\Administrator' in the security list at the bottom of SSMS. (Don't ask.)

I then restarted the SQL Server engine and now I can't connect to the instance as it is trying to connect with Windows Authentication using the deleted login. Managed to connect using a SQL Server login but it doesn't have enough grunt to repair the situation.

Yep, some mothers do have 'em.

Anyway out of this little conundrum?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops :-)

You'll have to go through the process described here, involving restarting the instance in single user mode, it will work so long as you are a member of (or can be added to) the local administrators group on the server:

[Troubleshooting: Connecting to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

It's not too complicated, but fiddly enough that you will only want to do this once :-)

Comment: Back from the dead. Thanks.